# How to extract strings between nth and mth occurence of a certain character in linux bash?

Tags: linux, string, bash

File1 contains:

```
a:b:c:d:any words here:e:f:G
```

w/r "any words here" can be a single word, two words, three words, and so on.

I want to get the string between the 4rd ":" and the 5th ":". So, that will be "any words here".

My initial idea was to replace ":" with space then, use awk to print.. but since the string i want to extract can be composed of multiple words, it will not accurately work.

Comment: `use awk to print` You can choose the separator. `awk -F:` Use `cut`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Can you please elaborate? thanks!

Comment: `echo 'a:b:c:d:any words here:e:f:G' |cut -f 5 -d:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cut` command allow you to split a line based on a delimiter, and extract required fields from it

In your example,

```
> echo 'a:b:c:d:any words here:e:f:G' |cut -f 5 -d:
```

should give you

```
any words here
```

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`

```
$ echo 'a:b:c:d:any words here:e:f:G' | awk -F: '{print $5}'
any words here
```

Or by creating an array with `IFS` changed to `:`

```
$ IFS=: words=( $(echo 'a:b:c:d:any words here:e:f:G') ); echo ${words[4]}
any words here
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is just 1 line input you can use the bash regex. It is more of a pain if you want to return more than 1 field, but for 1 field it is easy enough:

```
f=3
[[ "1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8" =~ (^([^:]*:){$f,$f})([^:]*)(:|$) ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
4
```